# Filter search results if variables are not empty

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement, where-clause

I'm pretty new to PHP / MySQL .. so be easy on me please :)

I want to filter a 'SELECT' function where variables are '!empty'. Otherwise 'SELECT * FROM' database.

Here is my code..

```
<form id="search" method="post" action="search.php">
<fieldset>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='yes'/>
<label id="label" for="type">Type</label>
<select name="type" id="type" size="1">
<option value="" selected>Any</option>
<option value="house">House</option>
<option value="flat">Flat</option>
<option value="apartment">Apartment</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label id='label' for='area'>Area</label>
<select name="area" id="area" size="1">
<option value="" selected>Any</option>
<option value="mtpleasant">Mount Pleasant</option>
<option value="townhill">Townhill</option>
<option value="mayhill">Mayhill</option>
<option value="town">Town Centre</option>
<option value="maritime">Maritime Quarter</option>
<option value="brynmill">Brynmill</option>
<option value="sketty">Sketty</option>
<option value="uplands">Uplands</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<label id="label" for="rent">Max. Rent PCM</label>
<input type="text" name="rent" id="rent" value="">
<label id="label" for="deposit">Max. Deposit</label>
<input type="text" name="deposit" id="deposit" value="">
<div id='submit_container' height="90px" width="400px">
<button type='submit' class='search_submit' alt="Search"/>&nbsp;</button>
<a href="#" onclick="show('search_advanced');">Advanced Search &#187;</a>
<div id="search_advanced">
<label id="label" for="tenancy">Tenancy Length</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="tenancy" value="1-5"><span>1 - 6 months</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="tenancy" value="6-12"><span>6 - 12 months</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="tenancy" value="12+"><span>12+ months</span><br />
<label id="label" for="bedrooms">Bedrooms</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="1-3"><span>1-3</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="4-6"><span>4-6</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="bedrooms" value="6+"><span>6+</span><br/>
<label id="label" for="bathrooms">Bathrooms</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="bathrooms" value="1"><span>1</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="bathrooms" value="2+"><span>2+</span><br/>
<label id="label" for="communal">Communal</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="communal" value="1"><span>1</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="communal" value="2+"><span>2+</span><br/>
<label id="label" for="parking">Parking</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="parking" value="Y"><span>Yes</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="parking" value="N"><span>No</span><br/>
<label id="label" for="garden">Garden</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="garden" value="Y"><span>Yes</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="garden" value="N"><span>No</span><br/>
<label id="label" for="broadband">Broadband</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="broadband" value="Y"><span>Yes</span><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="broadband" value="N"><span>No</span><br/>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>


<?php
$type = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']): false);
$area = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['area']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['area']): false);
$rent = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['rent']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rent']): false);
$deposit = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['deposit']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deposit']): false);
$tenancy = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['tenancy']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tenancy']): false);
$bedrooms = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['bedrooms']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bedrooms']): false);
$bathrooms = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['bathrooms']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bathrooms']): false);
$communal = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['communal']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['communal']): false);
$parking = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['parking']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parking']): false);
$garden = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['garden']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['garden']): false);
$broadband = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['broadband']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['broadband']): false);

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1"; // no filtering

if ($type) { $query.=" AND 'type' = ".$type; } // type filter
if ($area) {$query.=" AND 'area' = ".$area;} // area filter
if ($rent) {$query.=" AND 'rent' < ".$rent;} // rent filter
if ($deposit) {$query.=" AND 'deposit' < ".$deposit;} // deposit filter
if ($tenancy) {$query.=" AND 'tenancy' = ".$tenancy;} // tenancy filter
if ($bedrooms) {$query.=" AND 'bedrooms' > ".$bedrooms;} // bedrooms filter
if ($bathrooms) {$query.=" AND 'bathrooms' > ".$bathrooms;} // bathrooms filter
if ($communal) {$query.=" AND 'communal' > ".$communal;} // communal filter
if ($parking) {$query.=" AND 'parking' = ".$parking);} // parking filter
if ($garden) {$query.=" AND 'garden' = ".$garden;} // garden filter
if ($broadband) {$query.=" AND 'broadband' = ".$broadband;} // broadband filter

$results = mysql_query($query); 

echo '<table border=0 cellpadding=3>';

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Type:</th><td>'.$info['type'] . '</td> ';
    echo '<th>Area:</th><td>'.$info['area'] . '</td> ';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm close with this, no? I'm getting the following error.

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a9137540/public_html/search.php on line 49

Line 49: while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
```

Please please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: error 1064 means you have a parse error. But I found an error in the code I gave you:You see there is a bracket closing at the end of the statement (after `:false`). Remove that. I updated my post. Please look at it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add isset() function in your condition:

```
(isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']): false;
```

But your query is open to SQL injection attack. Make sure you sanitize $_POST items first.

For the error:
You most probably have query error.
Instead of simply doing $result=mysql_query($query); and try to use the $result, make sure the query executes successfully.

```
if(!mysql_query($query)){
  echo mysql_errno();
  exit;
}
```

This will at least help you to identify the error.

Additional info.
Try to change the

if ($area) {$query.=" AND 'area' = ".$area;}`

to

`if ($area) {$query.="' AND 'area' = '".$area;}`
(I add 'qoute' after `$query.="` and before `".$area`.

SQL needs to enclose values (other than numbers) with quotes.

Comment: This hasn't fixed it either I'm afraid :( Still getting a parse error at line 33 'if ($type) { $query.=" AND 'type' = ".$type); } // type filter'

Comment: @SimonKnight, please check line 32. You have missed to add ";" at the end.

Comment: Okay I've changed this. Now getting different error. 'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a9137540/public_html/search.php on line 49'

Comment: @Hasina I've edited my code to the above edited question. I'm now getting a different error.

Comment: @simon knight sorry I missed ')' at the end of the ternary condition. I updated the post. Please look at it

Comment: @Bere I don't think there was anything wrong with that code, changing to your advised code has given me new errors.  I'm getting a mysql_fetch_array() error. See above edited question

Comment: @simon please see my update post. I hope it will work this time!

Comment: @Bere  Still not working I'm afraid :( Ive edited my code to your above answer. $type = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']): false); $query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1"; if (isset($type)) { $query.="' AND 'type' = '".$type; } echo $query; if(!mysql_query($query)){ echo mysql_errno(); exit; } $results = mysql_query($query); I am getting the error number 1064 after the $query echo. Still with no results shown

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 isset($_POST['type'])
```

instead of

```
!empty($_POST['type'])
```

Comment: This hasn't helped I'm afraid :( I'm still getting the following error. 
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/a9137540/public_html/search.php on line 33

Comment: please add ";" after "$query = ("SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1")".

let me know if its working.

Comment: line now reads.. '$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1"; // no filtering' ..Still not working :(

Comment: @dianuj I've edited my code to the above edited question, I'm now getting a different error.

Answer (score 0):

what is the closing bracket **)** purpose at the end in each `if` condition

Try this one

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1";
if (isset($type)) { $query.=" AND `type` = '".$type."' "; } // type filter
if (isset($area)) {$query.=" AND `area` = '".$area."' "; }  // area filter
if (isset($rent)) {$query.=" AND `rent` < '".$rent."' "; } // rent filter
if (isset($deposit)) {$query.=" AND `deposit` < '".$deposit."' "; } // deposit filter
if (isset($tenancy)) {$query.=" AND `tenancy` = '".$tenancy."' "; } // tenancy filter
if (isset($bedrooms)) {$query.=" AND `bedrooms` > '".$bedrooms."' "; } // bedrooms filter
if (isset($bathrooms)) {$query.=" AND `bathrooms` > '".$bathrooms."' "; } // bathrooms filter
if (isset($communal)) {$query.=" AND `communal` > '".$communal."' "; } // communal filter
if (isset($parking)) {$query.=" AND `parking` = '".$parking."' "; } // parking filter
if (isset($garden)) {$query.=" AND `garden` = '".$garden."' "; } // garden filter
if (isset($broadband)) {$query.=" AND `broadband` = '".$broadband."' "; } // broadband filter
```

And to check that any variable is assigned or not you have to use `isset`

Comment: okay thanks for your help. I've changed the to the following for all variables..

'
$type = (isset($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST['type']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']): false);

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1"; /'/ no filtering

if ($type) { $query.=" AND 'type' = ".$type; } // type filter
'

I'm now getting a different error.. 

'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a9137540/public_html/search.php on line 49' 

:(

Comment: can you add this `echo $query;` before `$results = mysql_query($query);` and post in your question that what exactly your query looks like

Comment: SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1 AND 'type' = AND 'area' = AND 'rent' < AND 'deposit' < AND 'tenancy' = AND 'bedrooms' > AND 'bathrooms' > AND 'communal' > AND 'parking' = AND 'garden' = AND 'broadband' =

Comment: Okay I've edited to the above code. I'm still getting a mysql_fetch_array() error. This is the new echo $query. SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1 AND 'type' = '' AND 'area' = '' AND 'rent' < '' AND 'deposit' < '' AND 'tenancy' = '' AND 'bedrooms' > '' AND 'bathrooms' > '' AND 'communal' > '' AND 'parking' = '' AND 'garden' = '' AND 'broadband' = ''

Comment: @SimonKnight i had replaced ' with `  please see my answer

Comment: @simon I have updated my answer. I hope it will work this time.

Comment: @dianuj  I have edited my code to match your answer. if (isset($type)) { $query.=" AND `type` = '".$type."' "; } // type filter. This is the echo $query line: SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 1=1 AND `type` = '' AND `area` = '' AND `rent` < '' AND `deposit` < '' AND `tenancy` = '' AND `bedrooms` > '' AND `bathrooms` > '' AND `communal` > '' AND `parking` = '' AND `garden` = '' AND `broadband` = ''. And since adding the echo mysql_errno() I am getting error 1064

Comment: run your query in phpmyadmin and see what syntax error is occuring

Comment: Thanks @dianuj Using phpmyadmin I managed to work out what the problem with syntax was. Many thanks for your help

Comment: you are welcome if i was right then do not forgot to accept the answer as solved